# Switching HTML Pages (Not Asynchronously) after Google Firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am trying to make a website where I click a button to sign in with google and then, it goes to a new html page.

However, **when the new google sign in window pops up, it is *immediately* closed and the html page changes**.

> - I do want the html page to change, but: **do I need the google sign in
>
>     to work first?**
> - Is there a way to **wait until the user logs in before going to the      new page?**

I was thinking if there was a boolean method to see if the login succeeded but I could not find any.

Could you please help me?

```
    <html>
      <head>
//connect to css and javascript file
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="hackathon.css">
        <script src=scripts.js></script>
      </head>

      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js"></script>
      <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyAOWTFIhpydI27RMa_JzOW0Ffyajb9sTqg",
        authDomain: "teach-and-learn-cd50e.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://teach-and-learn-cd50e.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "teach-and-learn-cd50e",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "412721016471"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      </script>

      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
//create the header

<p><center><font face="Verdana" size="7" color="white">Teach and Learn</font></p>
    //login button
      <button class="button1">Log In</button>
    //google sign in 
      <script type="text/javascript">
        button=document.querySelector('button')
        database=firebase.database()
        reference=database.ref()
        button.onclick=function(){
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
           var token = result.credential.accessToken;
           var user = result.user;
           }).catch(function(error) {
           var errorCode = error.code;
           var errorMessage = error.message;
           var email = error.email;
           var credential = error.credential;
        })

         //immediately goes to this page without giving the use 
         //opportunity to sign in
        //main.html is loaded and the sign in window is closed
        window.location.href="./main.html";

      </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could it be you are already signed into google?

Answer (score 1):

If the login succeeds, the code inside of `function(result)` will run. If the login fails, the code inside of `function(error)` will run. Anything inside the `then` will wait until you try to login. Put the redirection code inside of the then.

I revised your code on this CodePen, so you can try it out for yourself. It's very important that you get rid of the second `window.location.href = "./main.html";` in the code.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoOeyv?editors=1000

Comment: This does not work. It gives me this Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

Comment: Take a look at my edits. I setup a CodePen so you can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

move the window.location.href into the callback?

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {

    //..
    window.location.href="./main.html";

}).catch(function(error) {
    //..
});
```

Comment: This gives me a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: @RandomPerson please send over a jsfiddle with your updated code.